# Unable to load simulator iOS

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am getting following error whenever I try to run my xcode project after this my xcode also becomes unresponsive.

I have already tried the following things:
1.Checked if command line tools is correct
2.Reset simulator  settings, deleted them and added them again
3. Tried for various iOS version and relevant simulator
4.Uninstalled xcode and added the latest one 
5. Rebooted atleast a thousand times

Also my xcode is in application folder itself.
Other than running everything is working fine.

**UPDATE:**

i upadted my macOS and something went wrong there and hence the rendering issue. i Just did a fresh os install and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: which Xcode are you using?

Comment: I have tried with xcode 8,7.1 and 7.3